# how to print a word but after every new line it adds a letter to it

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code that prints out whatever the user puts into the input but on the new line, it adds the next letter of their name.

```
Name: Caden
c
ca
cad    
cade
caden
```

The code that I have now almost does it, it prints it with an extra line at the start and it doesn't finish the name by the last letter, here is my code.

```
name = input("Name: ")
name = name[::-1]
for i in range(len(name)):
  print(name[:i])
print(name)
```

I set up a workaround at the end where I have print(name) this finishes off the rest of the name but surely there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

1. The code you currently have will print all characters of the name, but in reverse.
   Remove `name = name[::-1]` to have it print normally.
2. If you want to print all characters of the name in your for loop, simply increase the range you are looping over by 1
3. Additionally, if you wish it to print in lower case (as in your example), you can format the string with `.lower()`:

```
name = input("Name: ").lower()
for i in range(len(name)+1):
    print(name[:i])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do it.

```
name = input("Name: ")

m = 1

for i in name:
    print(name[:m], sep="\n")
    m +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Teoman, I forgot to mention I wanted it in reverse, so I just added the name = name[::-1] to keep it reversed.

This was the final code that got it working for me.

```
name = input("Name: ")
name = name[::-1]

m = 1

for i in name:
    print(name[:m], sep="\n")
    m +=1
```